# Clojure "first" returns (for me) unexpeted result?

Tags: clojure

(first ["a" "b" "c"]) 
-> 
"c"

where I would expect:
(first ["a" "b" "c"]) 
-> 
"a"

I think I must have misunderstood something here ,any help appreciated!

Best Regards.

---

```
(defn binnd-to-name [name-string to-bind]
  (bind-to-name name-string to-bind))

(defmacro bind-to-name [name-string stuff-to-bind]
  `(def ~(symbol name-string) ~stuff-to-bind))

(defn bind-services [list-of-services]
  (if (empty? list-of-services)
    nil
    (do
      (binnd-to-name (first (first list-of-services)) (last (first list-of-services)))
        (bind-services (rest list-of-services)))))

(bind-services [["*my-service*" se.foo.bar.service.ExampleService]])
```

ExampleService is a Java class on the classpath, which I want to bind to the symbol *my-service*. 
The idea is to loop through a list of name-value pairs and bind each name to the value. 
It is not working as expected though.

So somehow in this code something evaluated into "def first last" apparently.

Comment: Huh? No way! What is your Clojure version?

Comment: Would you please post your code?

Comment: Where did you get 1.5.3? I only see 1.5.1: http://clojure.org/downloads

Comment: Sorry, my bad, 1.5.1 it is.

Comment: `first` is working properly you can check yourself inserting print statements inside bind-to-name, problem is with `def` macro expansion, I've added an answer with a working bind-services

Comment: I guess it would be a nice feature if there was a way to warn on reasignment of top level vars, similar to warn on reflection to aid in debugging.

Comment: @user1436026: Clojure is a tool for professionals. All the power in the world is at your fingertips - including the power to completely screw things up! Handle With Care...  :-)

Comment: @Bob Jarvis I meant an optional dynamic var that could be set only to aid in debugging, thus making professionals' lives that much easier... Again, similar to *warn-on-reflection* http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/*warn-on-reflection*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with your macros not expanding as you expect

```
(defmacro bind-to-name [name-string stuff-to-bind]
  `(def ~(symbol name-string) ~stuff-to-bind))

(defmacro bind-services [services]
  `(do
     ~@(for [s services]
         `(bind-to-name ~(first s) ~(second s)))))

(bind-services [["*my-service*" se.foo.bar.service.ExampleService]])
```

If you try this approach your `def symbol` sequence will properly expand.

Comment: Aha, a macro inside a macro, beautiful! Works perfecty, many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No way!

```
user=> (doc first)
-------------------------
clojure.core/first
([coll])
  Returns the first item in the collection. Calls seq on its
      argument. If coll is nil, returns nil.

user=> (first ["a" "b" "c"])
"a"
```

Comment: Hard to read in the comment, but the symbol "first" is actaully bound to the function "last". Weird?

Comment: Ok, now I restarted my Repl and first is again bound to first. Order restored, many thanks for your reply!

Comment: @AndersG at any point in your code, did you bind a the symbol `first` to some value? Remember that clojure does not store functions and data separately.

Comment: @noisesmith I understand now that it must have been my "awesome" macro for binding some variables that I made that accidentally bound "first" to "last"